# Pattern matching overhead?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

I'm new to Scala and Spark and I'm working on the implementation of an algorithm. I'm wondering if the usage of scala pattern matching is convenient in order to increase code readability or if it actually introduces a significant overhead during the execution. Frequently I have to manage complex objects/nested tuples in map functions, so I ask you what is the usual approach. Usually there is not a real comparison in my matches, it is just something like

```
COLLECTION.map{ case (A, (_,(C,_))) => do something with A and C) }
```

instead of

```
COLLECTION.map(pair => do something with pair._1 and pair._2._2._1)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: to test the performance of the algorithm, you just put the time measurement around the algorithm execution ... that, or have benchmarks of different algorithms use the same scaffolding around them, so that the overhead time, however high, is constant. Alternatively, just write both variants with the same algorithm, measure execution time, and decide for yourself which one is better.

Comment: @Dima my question is different and is not related to the general algorithm testing, but to the specific scala pattern matching. Considering that last phrase was confusing for you I remove it from the question.

Comment: in that case, the answer is, there is no noticeable difference. It's a question of taste.

Answer (score 2):

The `unapply` function that the compiler invokes for pattern matching in your first code example is likely to be more expensive than the 2nd example, which does not require introspection or runtime testing of value or type. However, the 2nd example will fail unless all of the the elements in collection are of the expected type, and you have not indicated to the compiler which type is expected.

Whether or not the pattern matching in the first example incurs significant overhead depends on how often it is called, relative to the computation in the rest of the program.

Comment: unapply does not require introspection. If elements are of wrong type both ways will fail.

Comment: Matches can be made for type and or value. If unapply is called then it has a cost. There are many ways that match can work. Match by type uses introspection

Comment: No `unapply` was had in this pattern.

Comment: @Martijn `case (A, (_,(C,_)))` is actually a call to `unapply`. It's "cost" is creating and destroying a stack frame, which is for all practical purposes, "free".

Comment: @MikeSlinn finding out the type of a variable hasn't been an expensive operation since (I think) java 4 or so ... Besides, if you need to know the type, you are going to have to pay that price regardless, pattern matching or no pattern matching. And, once again, there is NO INTROSPECTION in the first example.

Comment: @Dima I'm not seeing an unapply call back in generated bytecode, and according to the SLS this should be a constructor pattern which can be implemented as just a type test (`ifInstanceOf`/`asInstanceOf` pair). Also, `Tuple2` doesn't have a companion object, so no `unapply` there.

Comment: @Martijn it's `Product2.unapply`. I am not sure why you are not seeing it in bytecode, maybe, it's getting inlined by the compiler (like I said, the call is really "free" for all practical purposes), but it definitely _does_ call the `unapply`. You can verify it by setting a breakpoint in a debugger if you want.

Comment: No operation is free, not even no-ops. Everything incurs noticeable overhead if they are performed frequently enough. For example, one time-honored way to work around timing issues is to introduce no-ops.

Answer (score 1):

The matching has very little overhead. The tuple match lifts the parameters directly into a tuple, Tuple patterns aren't handled with `unapply`. The `f` in

```
class Foo {
  val f: ((Double, Int)) => Double = { case (d, i) => d + i }
}
```

is compiled (without opimization flags) in to

```
     0: aload_0
     1: astore_3
     2: aload_3
     3: ifnull        21
     6: aload_3
     7: invokevirtual #35                 // Method scala/Tuple2._2$mcD$sp:()D
    10: dstore        4
    12: dload         4
    14: iconst_1
    15: i2d
    16: dadd
    17: dstore_1
    18: goto          33
    21: goto          24
    24: new           #37                 // class scala/MatchError
    27: dup
    28: aload_3
    29: invokespecial #41                 // Method scala/MatchError."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    32: athrow
    33: dload_1
    34: dreturn
```

There is one (fruitless) test there for a match error.

How much overhead you find acceptable can't really be answered in general.